# Microsoft Azure Payment Options

Tags: azure, payment, free, credit-card

I want to create an **Microsoft Azure** free account with my credit card.
But I might purchase something by mistake.
So if I deleted my credit card payment option from my **Microsoft Azure Free Account will the subscription end or not** *free subscription 12 months*. Because I am a student and scared of being paying to Azure without my knowledge. Also I tried my luck for GitHub Student Developer Pack, but no. So I just want to know to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the single payment option on your subscription, you can't simply delete it. The only option to free the card is to cancel subscription or replace it with any other credit card.

[image]

[image]